# Can the Dock bar reserve it's horizontal space even if window is maximized?

Tags: macos, dock, window-manager, fullscreen

I don't want to have the dock bar auto-hiding/showing, so I have it always enabled.
When I maximize a window, two things happen:

- either it goes fullscreen so it hides the dock
- or I make it bigger (with any tool like snaptool etc) but it goes behind the dock , so I can't access some parts of windows (like in Chrome pages)

is it possible (is there any app) that makes the dock behave more like a windows taskbar?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to make a window bigger than the size left by the Dock, by dragging the bottom of a window yourself, you will notice that you can't do it. This is because the Dock *already* behaves like a Windows Taskbar: you can move windows behind it but not resize windows beyond it.

The problem lies with the tool that you are using to resize the window-it is extending the window more than it should do. Try using a different tool to do the resizing or resize the windows yourself.

Comment: months after getting the Mac, I still cannot understand and predict the logic of maximizing/fullscreen windows... :(

Comment: Actually I checked it again - you're partially right. I use two monitors and the thing is, the Dock appears each time to one monitor depending on the one you're active (I think?) That's where the problem starts..